I am using RDLC for reports in Visual Studio 2022 (.NET). The Page Total Box and Report Total box do not come under table. Ti comes at footer of page
Actual Photo Of Report
I was trying to get the page total and report total below the table in rdlc report. I have use footer to get page total but if there is another way to get page total in tablix itself (without grouping), please let me know. The footer should come directly below the tablix if next page has only 2-3 rows.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
